# Validation on Opportunity Stage

Tags: apex, validation

I have a validation on Opportunity which should accept Stage = 'Closed Won' when Amount > 10000. I have tried below validation.

```
NOT(
IF((Amount >10000),TRUE,FALSE)&&
IF( TEXT(StageName) == "Closed Won", TRUE,FALSE)  
)
```

I want the stage value to accept any other value if the Amount is < 10000. Can anyone help me how to achieve this...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validations rule fire only if the condition is true. Hence for your use case, make sure condition evaluates to true. Try below code

```
Amount > 10000 && NOT(ISPICKVAL(stageName, “Closed Won”))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mohith. It worked.